# Adding server blocks to Nginx (Puma or Unicorn) configuration to load different environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I had once viewed a site (name forgotten) , which allowed the client to enter the environment which he wants to see (test,development or production) and the app loaded that environment exactly . Being a Ruby on rails developer , i know that it's achievable but somehow i am falling short of guidance on how to go on achieving it . What are the tools i should be using and how i can load different environments in a single app . Is it just some changes on the server side or do i need to make changes in my code too to suit the requirement . Looking forward to some useful inputs as i am still new to web development and this the place to ask and share , please spare if you find this a noob question :)

Comment: Couldn't it just have been three Rails servers, each running one of the environments and being available under a different port, subdomain or path prefix? I doubt it's possible to have a Rails server switch environments on the fly - that would affect all users currently on the site.

Comment: It's possible but i wanted to know what if there is a tool to make it happen this way , rails has always surprised me with new things :)